# Object of type CarBrandForm is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

CarBrandForm in this example is a ModelForm.

```
def post(self,request):
    if request.method== "POST":
        form=CarBrandForm(request.POST)
        if form is not None:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                request.session['user']=form
                return render(request,'carbrand/branddetails.html')
        return render(request,'carbrand/carbrandregister.html')
```

**Showing error when i started to store session variable. This is the first iam using session, So if there is any improvments and precaution that i have to take is always welcome. Thankyou!**

Comment: Why do you try to use sessions here? Why do you want to store the `form`?

Comment: For registering the "brand"(Type of user in here), and to ensure that user who have logged in can only access the website

Comment: but your form already saves the object, so there is no need to keep the form. Furthermore storing this in the session will not ensure that only the logged in use can access a view. That is something that is enforced with the `@login_required` decorator and with proper filtering of the querysets.

Comment: but if this person access any other page without logging in. Then is there any way to ensure that don't happen?

Comment: this is what `@login_required` is all about: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator